# FS2 join Cannot prove that Seq[fs2.Stream[cats.effect.IO,Int]] <:< fs2.Stream[cats.effect.IO,O2]

Tags: scala, scala-cats, scalaz-stream, fs2

I'm trying to use fs2 streams 0.10.0-M9 and doobie version 0.5.0-M9 for getting a sequence of objects from an http call which I want to then insert into a postgres database but I'm having issues structuring this code, getting the following error:

> Error:(49, 12) Cannot prove that Seq[fs2.Stream[cats.effect.IO,Int]]
>   <:< fs2.Stream[cats.effect.IO,O2].
>         .join(100)

What i want to do is run the insert statements concurrently once the call to the web service returns. Here's the code:

```
fetchProducts(date).map{items  =>
        items.map( i =>
          Stream.eval(upsertProductIO(i).transact(xa))
        )
      }
      .join(100)
      .run
      .unsafeRunSync()

//rest call
def fetchProducts(changeDate: String): Stream[IO, Seq[Product]] = {
//rest call here
}

//DAO code
def upsertProductIO(p: Product): ConnectionIO[Int] = {
  upsertProduct(p).run
}
```

Comment: Jose, could you also say which versions of the libraries do you use? There seem to be a major difference between versions.

Comment: Added version fs2 0.10.0-M9 and doobie 0.5.0-M9

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have a `Seq[Stream[IO, Seq[Product]]`, What you want, rather, is a `Stream[IO, Seq[Product]]`, which you can do with a `Foldable` type class instance:

```
import cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

fetchProducts(date).map { items =>
   items.map(i => Stream.eval(upsertProductIO(i).transact(xa)))
}.map(seqOfStream.toList.sequence)
 .join(100)
 .run
 .unsafeRunSync()
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code as you suggested but I'm getting a similar error:   

`fetchProducts("2017-12-10T06:17:37:557-0400").map { items =>
      items.map(i => Stream.eval(upsertProductIO(i).transact(ProductDao.xa)))
    }.map(is => is.toList.sequence)
      .join(100)
      .run
      .unsafeRunSync()`

Error:(38, 27) Cannot prove that fs2.Stream[cats.effect.IO,Int] <:< G[A].
    }.map(is => is.toList.sequence)

Comment: @JoseH.Martinez, what version of the Scala compiler do you use? Yuval's code compiles for me with `scalaVersion := "2.11.11"` and `scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"` and fails without `-Ypartial-unification` with an error quite similar to yours.

Comment: I'm on   scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

Comment: Did you try compiling with sbt?

Comment: @JoseH.Martinez ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using sbt. I noticed the problem exists when I change def upsertProductIO(p: Seq[Product]) to def upsertProductIO(p: Product)

Comment: what's the proper way to accomplish this using upsertProductIO(p: Product)   @YuvalItzchakov

Comment: @JoseH.Martinez Do you still return a `Stream[IO, Seq[Product]]` from `fetchProducts`?

Comment: Yes. I wonder if I can take that sequence and then run multiple inserts for each product. Or, make fetchProducts return the sequence of products as a stream rather than a sequence.